# I need to use the table name as a variable in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cursor

I made a function that I need to call multiple times for different tables, however when trying to use the table name as an input variable in the function, it gives me an error. I read that it is possible if an "execute" statement is used, however I don't know how to apply it

the code I have is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cta_tiempos7 (nomLD text, nomRe text, subst text, out FIM) AS $$

declare
        resta_ok int;
        cie_res int;
        t_abi timestamp;
        t_cie timestamp;
        t_fuera interval;
        t_switc interval;
        tiempos Record; 
        cur_evento Cursor for select  nombre, señal as signal, estampa from subst
                    where nombre in (nomLD, nomRe) and señal in ('Indicacion 52 Cerrado', 'Indicacion 52 abierto');

begin
.
.
.
.
.
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: what the error says?

Comment: ERROR:  relation "subst" does not exist
LINE 1: select  nombre, señal as signal, estampa from subst
                                                      ^
QUERY:  select  nombre, señal as signal, estampa from subst
     where nombre in (nomLD, nomRe) and señal in ('Indicacion 52 Cerrado', 'Indicacion 52 abierto') 
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function cta_tiempos5(text,text,text) line 24 at FOR over cursor
SQL state: 42P01

Comment: Take a look at the [plpgsql cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) docs. In particular 42.7.2.2. OPEN FOR EXECUTE.